# How can I combine two half view with zstack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, split, zstack

I have a map pin view that represents an action.

[image: Action 1]

[image: Action 2]

This is the code

```
VStack {
                                ActionView(action: place.actions.first!)
                                    .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                                Text(self.displayPlaceName ? place.name : "")
                            }.overlay(
                                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.left.fill")
                                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270))
                                    .foregroundColor(place.actions.first!.color())
                                    .offset(y: 10)
                            )
```

The pin can represent only one action.

If there are two actions I would like to see half of both pin.
something like that.

[image: Expected result]

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Have you tried putting two of your `VStack{ActionView...}` , into a `HStack` with no spacing and the appropriate offset position?
 Or simply two of your `VStack{ActionView...}` at the same location, with the top one and covering half of the other, again using the appropriate offset.

Comment: I have not try this way, I'll give it a chance, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to hide half of a view is by applying a gradient mask. If we put two stops in the gradient at the same location with different colors, we get an instant change (a step) in the gradient rather than a smooth transition. Some code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Callout(borderColor: .brown) {
      Text("")
    }
    .mask {
      Rectangle()
        .fill(.linearGradient(
          stops: [
            // The specific color doesn't matter here, only its alpha,
            // which is 1 for .red and 0 for .clear.
            .init(color: .red, location: 0),
            .init(color: .red, location: 0.5),
            .init(color: .clear, location: 0.5),
            .init(color: .clear, location: 1.0),
          ],
          startPoint: .leading,
          endPoint: .trailing
        ))
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: the left half of a callout containing a soup bowl emoji]

We can swap the gradient colors to show the other half of the masked content. So, we can use a `ZStack` containing two callouts, with opposite halves masked:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Callout(borderColor: .brown) {
        Text("")
      }
      .mask {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.linearGradient(
            stops: [
              // The specific color doesn't matter here, only its alpha,
              // which is 1 for .red and 0 for .clear.
              .init(color: .red, location: 0),
              .init(color: .red, location: 0.5),
              .init(color: .clear, location: 0.5),
              .init(color: .clear, location: 1.0),
            ],
            startPoint: .leading,
            endPoint: .trailing
          ))
      }

      Callout(borderColor: .green) {
        Text("")
      }
      .mask {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.linearGradient(
            stops: [
              .init(color: .clear, location: 0),
              .init(color: .clear, location: 0.5),
              .init(color: .red, location: 0.5),
              .init(color: .red, location: 1.0),
            ],
            startPoint: .leading,
            endPoint: .trailing
          ))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: The left half shows a brown-framed callout of a soup bowl emoji. The right half shows a green-framed callout of a camera emoji.]

The result is a sharp cut between the two callouts. You can fade one into the other by replacing the step in the gradients with an interpolation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Callout(borderColor: .brown) {
        Text("")
      }
      .mask {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.linearGradient(
            stops: [
              .init(color: .red, location: 0),
              .init(color: .red, location: 0.4),   // <<< CHANGED
              .init(color: .clear, location: 0.6), // <<< CHANGED
              .init(color: .clear, location: 1.0),
            ],
            startPoint: .leading,
            endPoint: .trailing
          ))
      }

      Callout(borderColor: .green) {
        Text("")
      }
      .mask {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.linearGradient(
            stops: [
              .init(color: .clear, location: 0),
              .init(color: .clear, location: 0.4), // <<< CHANGED
              .init(color: .red, location: 0.6),   // <<< CHANGED
              .init(color: .red, location: 1.0),
            ],
            startPoint: .leading,
            endPoint: .trailing
          ))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: same as prior result except the left callout fades into the right callout over several pixel columns]

Here's the source for my `Callout` view in case you want to play with it:

```
struct CalloutBorderShape: Shape {
  let arrowHeight: CGFloat

  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let rect = rect.divided(atDistance: arrowHeight, from: .maxYEdge).remainder
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 3
    var path = Path()
    path.addRoundedRect(
      in: rect.insetBy(dx: 0.5 * lineWidth, dy: 0.5 * lineWidth),
      cornerSize: .init(width: 2 * lineWidth, height: 2 * lineWidth)
    )
    path = path.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: lineWidth))
    path.move(to: .init(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY + arrowHeight))
    path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX - arrowHeight, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX + arrowHeight, y: rect.maxY))
    path.closeSubpath()
    return path
  }
}

struct Callout<Content: View>: View {
  let borderColor: Color

  @ViewBuilder
  let content: Content

  var body: some View {
    content
      .padding(EdgeInsets(
        top: paddingSize,
        leading: paddingSize,
        bottom: paddingSize + arrowHeight,
        trailing: paddingSize
      ))
      .overlay {
        CalloutBorderShape(arrowHeight: arrowHeight)
          .fill(borderColor)
      }
  }

  private let paddingSize: CGFloat = 10
  private let arrowHeight: CGFloat = 6
}
```